# Coding Bat Warmup Question Java "Return true if the given string contains between 1 and 3 'e' chars."

Tags: java

The original question is:
"Return true if the given string contains between 1 and 3 'e' chars."

```
stringE("Hello") → true
stringE("Heelle") → true
stringE("Heelele") → false
```

---

This is my answer, but **WRONG**.

```
public boolean stringE(String str) {
  int count=0;
  
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
    String sub= str.substring(i,i++);
    if (sub.equals("e")) 
      count ++;
  }
  return (count>=1 && count<=3);

}
```

---

This is the solution the site presented.

```
public boolean stringE(String str) {
  int count = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == 'e') count++;
    // alternately: str.substring(i, i+1).equals("e")
  }

  return (count >= 1 && count <= 3);
}
```

---

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `String sub= str.substring(i,i++);` you increment the **i** variable here and in the `for` statement

Comment: Instead of `.substring(i, i+1).equals("e")` you can use `.regionMatches(i, "e", 0, 1)` to avoid expensive `substring` operations, when all you want to do with the sub-string, is matching. Of course, when you want to check a single `char`, using `str.charAt(i) == 'e'` is even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the 'i' counter twice:

```
public boolean stringE(String str) {
  int count=0;

  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
    String sub= str.substring(i,i+1); // <-- don't use i++
    if (sub.equals("e")) 
      count ++;
  }
  return (count>=1 && count<=3);
}
```

Comment: I see, that's right!  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the increment operator, Post increment to be more specific (i++).
The post increment operator updates the value of i variable after the current statement is executed.

So, this line of code

```
String sub = str.substring(i,i++);
```

is same as this,

```
String sub = str.substring(i,i);
i = i + 1;
```

As the same start and end index is passed in the substring method, the sub is always empty. Also, the post-increment operator increments the value of i during the iteration which should be avoided.

Thus, instead of using the increment operator, just add 1 to the i when passing it as an end index in the substring method.

```
String sub = str.substring(i,i+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`. Like following,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "Helloeee";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("e");
        System.out.println(exceedMax(p, s, 1, 3));
    }

    public static boolean exceedMax(Pattern p, String s, int min, int max) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        int count = 0;
        while (m.find() && count <= max) {
            count++;
        }
        return count < min || count > max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing char so use 'e' as string means two characters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).